# How to send parameters from a SmartCapture form to another Cloud Page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

I have a smartcapture form on a first page, it works properly and all data is sent to my Data Extension.
When the form is submitted, I need to update some fields (in Service Cloud but that's not the main point here).

To do so, I need to know the Id of the contact who filled the form. I created an hidden field in the smartCapture form for the Id. I'm able to send this Id value in my Data Extension in marketing cloud, but not to the second cloud page (defined in the URL REDIRECT part of the smartcapture form)

I thought I could write http://www.myLandingPage.com?id=%%Id%% or http://www.myLandingPage.com?id=%%=v(@id)=%% but I can't retrieve nothing with my RequestParameter('id')

Do you have any idea on how I can retrieve this data ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

David

Comment: Your query is not completely clear.... but as far as I understand, you have the value of 'id' in first cloud page and you need to pass it to second cloud page... if this is the case, try to store the 'id' value to hidden field and pass it to second page.. something like this <input name="id" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@id)=%%" />

Comment: Hi Vishal, thanks for your answer. Yes you understood my need. As I mentionned I created an hidden field in the smartCapture form for the Id, exactly as mentionned. But my RequestParameter('id') on the second cloud page is not working, it's empty. Any other idea ?

Comment: what does the link look like when you get redirected to the second CP? Can you see the Id in there?

Comment: no, that's the point, I can't see any ID. My URL is just http://www.myLandingPage.com?id=
It's like all parameters were lost between the 1st and the 2nd CP. And I guess that's really the case as I assume there is a middle page, the one used to send data to my DE.